# How to automatically fill in required parameter in Symfony

Tags: symfony, routes

So, all my routings looks like this

```
login: /studio/{uuid}/login
logout: /studio/uuid/logout
programs: /studio/{uuid}/programs
levels: /studio/{uuid}
```

and everytime I access the link via `{{ url('login|orwhathever') }}` I have to pass `uuid`. Because all my links will contain `uuid` I would like to automatize that.

Of course, previously I did not have `uuid` in the URL and it was just stored in the session if I needed it. But I recently noticed a problem when session expires it supposed to generate `login` url but it contains `uuid` parameter and because this parameter is NULL it will throw an error.

**So either it must be fixed by providing `{uuid}` to each url or
somehow pass `uuid` to Symfony logout method in `security.yml`**

```
    frontoffice_area:
        pattern:   ^/
        anonymous: ~
        simple_form:
            authenticator: security.user_authenticator
            login_path: login  #this needs uuid from somewhere
            check_path: validate
```

Comment: How you expect uuid from non authenticated user? Why just do simple /login route as everyone do?

Comment: Because simply each studio has own data presented and loaded by uuid.
It's impossible to make just /login because then which studio data I will show?

Comment: Simply redirect user after login to correct studio.